# What is the appropriate way to configure Firestore rules to only allow your web application to have Read and Write access?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

There is plenty of examples for rules for authenticated users but what about the web application itself?  I want my application to create, update and delete documents but don't want to leave it open to public access.

Comment: If you're not using Firebase Authentication, but you want to use Firestore in your app, then the database is effectively open for public access. There is no way to restrict usage of Firestore to just one app.

Comment: I am using Authentication for users.  Other "platforms" have the concept of service accounts so that the application itself can have authorization.

Comment: Security rules don't at all apply to access from Google Cloud service accounts.  Service account access bypasses all rules all of the time.  Security rules are unique to Firebase client access.

Comment: That makes sense.  So if I have a legitimate need for my application and users to access Firestore, I would need to utilize both the Firestore SDK & the Google Cloud SDK.  Thanks!